# How to set a value from another class

Tags: c#, .net

Its said that property should not be "Set" only (Code analysis rule CA1044 )and it should be "Get" as well. What should i do if I need to set value to a variable from some other class?

The will keep changing so I cannot pass it through constructor.

Shall I create a function for this as shown below?

```
class A
{

    public void SetValue()
    {
        b = new B();
        b.SetTest(10);
    }
}

class B
{
   int test;

   public void SetTest(int value)
   {
       test = value;
   }
}
```

What are the other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd agree with that it's a bit confusing with write only properties (from a client of the class points of view), so I try to avoid them and instead create a set method of some kind.

The way recommended by Microsoft also seems to be to rewrite it to a method (or make it read and write if suitable): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182165.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use a public setter and a private getter, in case you need to access the variable in its own class.

```
class B {
   public int test { private get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This seems better alternative to me. But If I can set the value from that class itself then why should have private set? Is it just to have both Set and Get in the property?

Comment: There is no point in setting a value, if you are not going to use that value somewhere. If it's only to trigger an action, then you are better off writing a method, as proposed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Who said a property should not use only set accessor? I don't see a design flaw in it. If there is one, I will be glad to learn something new:)

Comment: I think it can be confusing in the client code when there's a property that can't be read, it doesn't feel right to me. The "official" reason would be analysis warning CA1044 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182165.aspx

Comment: @ho - Thanks for the CA rule. I forgot to mention that in question. I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
   public int Test { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not really make much sense since you are not holding on to your instance of `B`, but you can do something like this:

```
class A 
{
    private B b;

    public A()
    {
        this.b = new B();
    }

    public void SetValue() 
    { 
        this.b.Test = 10;
    } 
} 

class B 
{ 
   int test; 
   public int Test
   {
       get{ return this.test; }
       set{ this.test = value; }
   }    
}
```

Another alternative is to make the `Test` property an autoproperty (where the framework generates the backing field), like so:

```
class B 
{ 
   public int Test{get; set;}
}
```